# What is the difference between next(err) and next(new Error(err)) in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, middleware

Is there any reason to write `next(new Error(err))` instead of `next(err)` in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any context I would presume that err is already an object (as it usually is in node), so there's no reason to create a new object to just pass it along.

You would create a new object in a situation where, well, you wanna create a new error :). As opposed to just passing the existing one along.

next(new Error('Something went wrong'));